# SQL Server - confusion about serializable isolation level

Tags: sql-server, database, isolation-level

I have read the article (https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/questions-about-t-sql-transaction-isolation-levels-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/) and I have a question according to:

"SERIALIZABLE: A query in the current transaction cannot read data modified by another transaction that has not yet committed. No other transaction can modify data being read by the current transaction until it completes, and no other transaction can insert new rows that would match the search condition in the current transaction until it completes. As a result, the Serializable isolation level prevents dirty reads, nonrepeatable reads, and phantom reads. However, it can have the biggest impact on performance, compared to the other isolation levels."

I am confused about inserting new rows which don't fulfill search condition from 1 session/query. Example below:

Let's suppose I have table

```
EmpID   FirstName
1       john
2       new employee
3       A new employee
```

And queries in separate tabs:

```
--session 1----------------------------------
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    SELECT FirstName FROM EmployeeInfo
    WHERE FirstName like 'new empl%'

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'  

    SELECT FirstName FROM EmployeeInfo
    WHERE FirstName like 'new empl%'

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

---------session 2---------------------------
begin transaction;

    UPDATE EmployeeInfo
    SET FirstName = 'frank'
    WHERE EmpID = 1;

commit transaction;

-----session 3----
insert into EmployeeInfo values('A new employe 2')
```

I execute queries one after the other: session 1, session 2, session 3.
I expected that session 1 won't stop session 2 and session 3 from being executed because updates and inserts from this session don't fulfill search condition which is used in the first query. However, in results, i can see that session 1 has to be finished (rollback) before session 2 and session 3 is executed.

However, while I use other search condition in session 1 like below:

```
--session 1
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

SELECT EmpID, FirstName FROM EmployeeInfo
WHERE EmpID = 2

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'  

SELECT FirstName FROM EmployeeInfo

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

then, session 2 and session 3 are completed independently of session 1.
Why is that? Why like condition block inserting while "=" don't?

Edited:
1. There is only a primary key on EmpID .

Comment: What is the definition of the table including indexes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because "no other transaction can insert new rows that would match the search condition in the current transaction until it completes".  And SQL Server enforces this by taking range locks that prevent a conflicting insert.

If you have an index on EmployeeInfo.FirstName, SQL may be able to take a narrow lock to enforce this.  But without an index, SQL takes a lock that prevents any inserts.  Also if the SELECT query predicate was not supportable with a index, it would block all inserts.

You can examine the current state of the locks with:

```
select @@spid this_session, *
from sys.dm_tran_locks
```

.  And note that this behavior, makes SERIALIZABLE a not-very-useful isolation level.  And you should really only ever use READ COMMITTED and SNAPSHOT, possibly adding locking hints for specific transactions.

Comment: Would you please expand upon your assertion that this behavior makes `serializable` not very useful? I find it to be a very useful isolation level and I would like to know more about what led you to the opposite conclusion.

Comment: This case really is a case-in-point.  A simple SELECT query blocked inserts on a whole table for a not-so-obvious reason.  So it tends to greatly reduce concurrency in your application.  And a nasty side-effect of this is that it creates lots of opportunities for deadlocks.  And there's not much upside to it, as the isolation behavior it guarantees is not very useful.

Comment: It sounds more like you are saying it isn't very useful as a _default_ isolation level. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I really don't like changing the isolation level _at all_.  I think it's simpler and more effective to use locking hints on individual queries as needed, inside a READ COMMITTED transaction.

Comment: I think I understand what you meant now. So you are saying `serializable` is a not-very-useful isolation level when using `set transaction isolation level serializable` as a connection level setting or in a procedure as opposed just using to hints like `with (serializable)`. Is that right?

Comment: Right.  And I only use the serializable hint with concurrent MERGE statements.  Using UPDLOCK is much more common, as it prevents concurrent reads with UPDLOCK.